# React js and flux user store security

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm concerned about how to use different roles in a React app. 
Let's say a user tries to login and send username, password to the server.
If the user is logged in he/she will have different roles in the application, like admin, user, etc.

```
{
   "_id" : 8937493874398,
   "role" : "user"
}
```

Is it safe to save this in a Flux store? Can the role be changed by a user in javascript console or something like that?

What is the proper way of handling this? We want to hide parts of the application from users that has role : user and allow things for role : admin

Comment: Anything on the client side shouldn't be trusted.  I think you don't want to hide parts of the application, you want to hide the functionality or data that those parts expose, which should all happen away from the client.  

So, if I was able to change my role from 'user' to 'elite-super-admin', I could see the elite-super-admin interface, but whatever data it would try to fetch would all be locked down by whatever api you call out to.

Comment: Yes, I will prevent actions to be taken on the server side. But there may be occasions where I absolutely don't want to show features for unauthorized users. Maybe they haven't payed for them etc. 

I haven't built SPA applications before and I can't find a great solution for this. @Crob

Comment: I agree with Crob. If your app requires important restrictions in the interface based on authentication levels, a SPA might not be the best solution. You could do frequent auth-calls  to the server to make sure the client has the correct role, but as Crob said: nothing on the client side should be trusted. If a user is smart enough to change a flux store from the console, exposing a useless admin interface for the user won’t be your biggest security concern.

Comment: Ok, so the solution is to not use AngularJS, React or any other frontend libraries for this kind of problems? I'm under the impression that most of the SPA applications in use right now handles some sort of roles, group etc.

Comment: That is not what I’m saying. But you will have to get used to the thought that everything you send to the client can be accessed. If the javascript source contains React/DOM code that exposes company secrets, then you have a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it’s not "safe". Everything you send/store on the client side can be accessed and modified.

You could have the login functionality separated from the React App. So after the user logs in using a standard request/response setup, you can return React components based on the user’s authentication level on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your scenario, I think you should have two different react apps, one for normal and other for admin/restricted users.